# PHP Logical operators

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have a really weird syntax issue. Can somebody tell me why this isn't working:

`if ( ! is_single() || ! is_archive() )`

but this is:
`if ( ! is_single() || is_archive() )`

and how I could get the first statement to work?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I was still editing the question when the answer came. Anyway, I should have mentioned that I meant the a syntax. I was aware that the logic of the two statements is not the same. So the `!` has to be put outside. Thanks guys.

Comment: What happens when you use the first statement?

Comment: you question is not clear, what do you want to achieve? I guess that you need `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Write our your logic in words.

Comment: What do you get when you put the following in your code: `echo var_dump(is_single()), ' ', var_dump(is_archive());` if they both are true, then both conditions are false.

Comment: both statements will give different results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` (negate) operator has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP. That is why you need to enclose your second expression in brackets:

```
if ( ! (is_single() || is_archive()) )
```

to get it work as you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if (!(is_single() || is_archive()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that this code is not working...

1. `if ( ! is_single() || ! is_archive() )`

...but this is:

1. `if ( ! is_single() || is_archive() )`

But it's not the same logic.

1. **NOT is_single()** OR **NOT is_archive()**
2. **NOT is_single()** OR **is_archive()**